# Create PDF showing only legal black bar markup in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-word-2013

My Word 2013 document has tracked changes. When I save to PDF, it includes all the tracked change information (including showing <strike>deleted</strike> text). This is despite me having the view setting configured as "Simple Markup".

My goal is to produce a PDF that only has the vertical bar in the left margin indicating parts of the document that have been altered. Is this possible?

I tried doing a comparison of the two documents (Review > Compare...), but the resulting document behaved exactly the same when saved as PDF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Click on the little arrow in the corner of Tracking portion of Review ribbon to get to `Track Changes Options`
2. Click `Advanced Options`
3. Change Markup for Insertions and Deletions to `(none)`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems that "Deletions" should rather be set to "hidden"

Comment: It worked fine for me with `(none)`.

Answer (score 1):

For users on macs with recent versions, there's no little arrow in the ribbons. Here's what worked for me:

1. Click on Markup Options Make sure that Insertions and Deletions is
   checked;
2. then click on Preferences
3. Under Markup, set Insertions to Color Only; Color to Auto; set
   Deletions to Hidden; set Changed lines to something other than None.

Comment: This works when you _print_ the document to a .pdf, but unfortunately the black bar does not appear when you _save_ the document as a .pdf