# How to print change bars but not the edit detail in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to figure out how to print the vertical change bars to indicate locations where a change occurred, but show these on the final text. I have simple markup chosen as my tracking, which it shows up correctly on my screen, but it prints all of the insertions and deletions. How do I print the revised text with the vertical change bars?

Comment: Are you talking about printing nothing but the little marker lines?  If so, there is no such feature because their location depends on the text.  You could do something like change the text color to white on a white background.

Comment: No, I guess my wording was poor. I want to print the text in "final" view, as well as, the vertical change bars. I'd like for the vertical change bars to show up just to indicate that a change has been made. To do this, I've selected "simple markup" view. However, when I go to print, all of the insertions and deletions are showing up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create PDF showing only legal black bar markup in Word 2013](https://superuser.com/questions/748814/create-pdf-showing-only-legal-black-bar-markup-in-word-2013)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Word 2010 by simply changing your Track Changes options.  (So assume it will also work for Word 2013 for you.)

Change your track changes options (on the Review tab, the second option under the Track Changes button:  Change Tracking Options will display the Track Changes Options dialog).

At the top, in the Markup section:
for Insertions set to (none) and Color alongside that option to Auto
for Deletions, set to Hidden and Color alongside that option to Auto

Changed lines set to which margin you want to show the vertical lines (mine defaults to Left border) and set Color as desired (mine defaults to Black).

If you are in Final: Show Markup, you should now see the change bars in the margin, and the final text (ie including any additions and deletions) (but without the colors/underlining/strikethrough you normally have).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it..

First select the 'review' tab, then at the 'Track Changes' button select the little down arrow at the bottom right. This gives you a sub-menu: select the 'Change Tracking Options..'.

Now change the Insertions, and Deletions option to '(none)', and change the 'Changed Lines:' to your desired placement, and change its colour to red, or black, or your choice.

So that is the change tracking sorted, now to do the printing..

Now adjust the 'Show Markup' drop down (for me it's the middle one), you will probably want to deselect the 'comments', and the 'formatting'.

The top option (tool tip of 'Display for Review') should still be 'Final: Show Markup' so that the lines will be in the printout.

Particularly removing the 'comments' stops the page width being adjusted if comments are still present when the document is printed.

[This](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T008765_Turning_Off_Track_Changes_Change_Bars.html) document was the source of inspiration to finally getting it to happen.

Comment: Additionally, if you just want the side bars, you have to go an extra mile. Using the review option, accept the deletion part of changes, but keep the insertions. If it is a pure deletion, retain an inserted whitespace (adding one if needed). With those extra changes you can then set the 'show insertion' to none (no character markings), but still have the side bars at all the right places.