# Create PDF showing only legal black bar markup in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-word-2016

The question is the same of [this old one](https://superuser.com/questions/748814/create-pdf-showing-only-legal-black-bar-markup-in-word-2013), but related to Word 2016. I want to *"create PDF showing only legal black bar markup: [...] my goal is to produce a PDF that only has the vertical bar in the left margin indicating parts of the document that have been altered."*

I have Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016, with Microsoft Word 2016 (16.0.11029.20045), and the same exact steps of [this accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/748988/229407) give no results in my scenario.

Any hidden options or removed features here?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "give no results", the change bars don't show up? The solution works for me in Word 2016 so the problem may be somewhere else

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad The .docx document looks fine (with _Simple Markup_ it shows only the change bars on the margin of the document), but when creating .pdf I always see extended markup (extended comments on the right side of the document) or nothing (in case I uncheck "Print Markup" option in "Print Settings").

Comment: Under "Track Changes Options", make sure "Balloons in All Markup view show:" is set to "Nothing"

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad that was my issue, thank you! I thought that option only affects the 'All Markup' view, not the 'Simple Markup'. But I was wrong!